# Не работает форма, после нажатия на отправку переходит на mail.php

Tags: css3, html5, bootstrap4

Код формы в index.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <h4>Оставь заявку в форме ниже</h4>
    <form action="mail.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Ваше имя:</label>
    <input type="name" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email1">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email1" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
    <label for="phone">Номер телефона:</label>
    <input type="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
    <label for="message">Сообщение:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Отправить сообщение</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Код обработчика mail.php

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YdLyaV

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понимаю, что Вы планируете сделать? Вам не нужен переход на mail.php?
Если Вы хотите, чтоб после нажатия не переходило на mail.php, то можно сделать AJAX запрос, который с этой формы все данные собирает и передает на mail.php и если все успешно редеректит куда требуется, если есть ошибка, то выдает.

Comment: После перехода он не отправляет.